# Breakout of while loop while scrolling inside a div

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

Scraping Google Maps reviews. How can I break out of the `while` loop when it reaches the end of the reviews? Where am I making the mistake?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import csv


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
header_added = False
with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        driver.get(url) #line
        driver.maximize_window()
        # Page Title
        title = driver.title
        ftitle = title.split("-")
        title = ftitle[0]
        old_reviews = set()
        time.sleep(3)
        last_count = 0
        while True:
            scroll_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout section-scrollbox cYB2Ge-oHo7ed cYB2Ge-ti6hGc"]')))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scroll_div)  # Scroll
            reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout"]//div[@aria-label]')))
            ans = set(reviews) - set(old_reviews)  # Remove duplicate reviews
            new_count = len(reviews)
            # Reviews Div
            for div in ans:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", div)
                name = div.get_attribute('aria-label')

                photo_url = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')

                rating = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ODSEW-ShBeI-H1e3jb"]').get_attribute(
                    'aria-label')

                try:
                    image_links = []
                    image_div = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="ODSEW-ShBeI-Jz7rA"]')
                    images = image_div.find_elements_by_xpath('button')
                    for img in images:
                        im_link = img.value_of_css_property('background-image')
                        im_link = im_link[5:]
                        im_link = im_link[:-2]
                        image_links.append(im_link)

                except:
                    image_links = ''
                    pass
                try:
                    div.find_element_by_xpath('.//jsl//button').click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                except:
                    pass
                comment = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ODSEW-ShBeI-text"]').text

                dict1 = {'Title': title, "Name": name, "Profile": photo_url, "Rating": rating,
                         "Comment": comment, "Images Posted": image_links}
                with open(f'Google_reviews_for_{title}.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
                    w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
                    if not header_added:
                        w.writeheader()
                        header_added = True
                    w.writerow(dict1)
                old_reviews = reviews
                if last_count == new_count:
                    break
                last_count = new_count
```

The URL:- https://www.google.com/maps/place/El+TabanKo/@42.848117,-2.6741402,19z/data=!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0xd4fc26be313bc85:0xb10d327c782f87fa!2sCorrer%C3%ADa+Kalea,+45,+01001+Gasteiz,+Araba!3b1!8m2!3d42.8480012!4d-2.6737255!3m6!1s0xd4fc26be26c5be1:0x5f5e0ee05fe08041!8m2!3d42.8481171!4d-2.6735931!9m1!1b1

Comment: Is `if last_count == new_count:` where you want to exit the while loop?

Comment: You are only breaking the for loop, not the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `break` try using `return`.
Since your `break` is inside a `for` loop it takes you out of the `for` loop, but you are still inside endless loop of `while True:`
To use `return` your code should be inside a method.
**UPD**
You don't update the `new_count` inside the internal `for` loop!!!

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import csv
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
header_added = False
with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        driver.get(url) #line
        driver.maximize_window()
        # Page Title
        title = driver.title
        ftitle = title.split("-")
        title = ftitle[0]
        old_reviews = set()
        time.sleep(3)
        last_count = 0
        while True:
            scroll_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout section-scrollbox cYB2Ge-oHo7ed cYB2Ge-ti6hGc"]')))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scroll_div)  # Scroll
            reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout"]//div[@aria-label]')))
            ans = set(reviews) - set(old_reviews)  # Remove duplicate reviews
            new_count = len(reviews)
            # Reviews Div
            for div in ans:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", div)
                name = div.get_attribute('aria-label')
    
                photo_url = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    
                rating = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ODSEW-ShBeI-H1e3jb"]').get_attribute(
                        'aria-label')
    
                try:
                    image_links = []
                    image_div = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="ODSEW-ShBeI-Jz7rA"]')
                    images = image_div.find_elements_by_xpath('button')
                    for img in images:
                        im_link = img.value_of_css_property('background-image')
                        im_link = im_link[5:]
                        im_link = im_link[:-2]
                        image_links.append(im_link)
    
                except:
                    image_links = ''
                    pass
                try:
                    div.find_element_by_xpath('.//jsl//button').click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                except:
                    pass
                comment = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ODSEW-ShBeI-text"]').text
    
                dict1 = {'Title': title, "Name": name, "Profile": photo_url, "Rating": rating,
                             "Comment": comment, "Images Posted": image_links}
                with open(f'Google_reviews_for_{title}.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
                    w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
                    if not header_added:
                        w.writeheader()
                        header_added = True
                    w.writerow(dict1)
            old_reviews = reviews
            if last_count == new_count:
                break
            last_count = new_count
```

Comment: This breaks the loop instantly. I don't know but somehow the condition becomes True almost instantly. For the same code...strange.

Comment: That means the flow logic is wrong. I tried to understand it but leaved it founding it strange and unclear.

Comment: Added the full code. This should be fairly straight-forward, however the rendering of the reviews also is a bit weird.

Comment: Not sure this will work and this is definitely ugly, but please insert several sleeps inside the code. 1) before the first `driver.execute_script(`  2) and after it 3) maybe also after the second scrolling. Let me know if that changed the situation

Comment: `presence_of_all_elements_located` returns list of elements found once at least one element fulfilling the expected condition is found. That's why I advising you to put sleeps to see if it will work better with sleeps, the elements are fully loaded before the lists of elements are collected

Comment: No. Again..breaks the loop instantly.

Comment: @AbhishekRai You don't update the `new_count` inside the internal `for` loop!!!

Comment: `new_count = len(reviews)` ..isn't this there? Inside the `for` loop? I don't get it.

Comment: No! it is inside the `while` but before the `for`. This is why `for` is not working and by changing from `break` to `return` exits immediately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234928/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to exit out of the while loop here:

```
if last_count == new_count:
    break
```

What you are doing now is exiting out of the for loop and not the while loop.
In order to exit the while loop you need to set a condition, like this:

```
exit_condition = False
last_count = 0
old_reviews =set()
while not exit_condition:
        scroll_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout section-scrollbox cYB2Ge-oHo7ed cYB2Ge-ti6hGc"]')))
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scroll_div)  # Scroll
        reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout"]//div[@aria-label]')))
        ans = set(reviews) - set(old_reviews)  # Remove duplicate reviews
        new_count = len(reviews)
        # Reviews Div
        for div in ans:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", div)
            name = div.get_attribute('aria-label')
            old_reviews = reviews
            if last_count == new_count:
                exit_condition = True
                break
            last_count = new_count
```

Comment: This is breaking the loop instantly.

Comment: Then for some reason your `new_count` is equal to `last_count` at the start. Try printing them and tell me what do you get